# First UNIQUE number from array. Elegant solution required

Tags: javascript

Hy Guys. I was asked to create a function that return first UNIQUE integer from given array of integers. In a case of success the function return the unique number in a case of failure  return -1. The complexity should be O(N*log(N))
My solution is:

```
function solution(A) {

    var returnNumber = -1;
    var tempArray = new Array();;

   for(i=0; i < A.length; i++){

      var newIndex = A[i];
     if( tempArray[newIndex] === undefined){
        tempArray[newIndex] = 1;
     }
     else{
        tempArray[newIndex] += 1;
     }
    }
   for(j = 0; j < A.length; j++){
     if(tempArray[A[j]] == 1){
       returnNumber = A[j];
       break;
     }
   }
    return returnNumber;
}

//var A =  [1, 4, 3, 3, 1, 2, 0, 0]; //returns 4
var A =  [22, 25, 3, 3, 1, 2, 0, 0,100,22,25,1,2]; // returns 100
solution(A)
```

Can somebody create more elegant solution? Any comments are welcome.

Comment: This might be more appropriate for [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: This function is actually `O(n)`...

Comment: If I am not dreaming, I saw an answer from a well established member few minutes ago! Where @volkinc said it was not O(N*log(N)) and he objected. Where did that answer go? It is unacceptable for a well established member to simply remove his answer like that. If someone has his name, let me fill a complain against his behaviour. He is well establish so that his vote could simply tear some other people down. He should be humble enough to accept his own mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

[EDIT]
how about:

```
// checks for duplictes before and after current node
function find1 (ls) {
    return ls.find(function (n, idx, ls) {
        return (idx == ls.indexOf(n)) && (-1 == ls.indexOf(n, idx + 1));
    });
}
```

looks elegant enough to me, and performs quite the same.

Comment: Would you mind explaining why and how this is an answer? It would greatly increase it's value.

Comment: The answer should be at JS

Comment: This returns `3`, not `100`.

Comment: @innoSPG: worst case, yes; best case would be O(N*log(N))

Comment: @publicoverride, best case would be O(N), ( better than O(N*log(N)) ) when the first Unique is at position 1, How many times are we in that case in the real life? The average case that is most of the time used  in complexity study will be O(N^2) for your algorithm. Think about it.

Answer (score 1):

1) Duplicate the array (O(N))

2) Write a quicksort to sort the copy (O(N*log(N))), then:

3) Search the first unique by:

- loop on the non sorted array
- for each element find its position in the sorted array using binary search algorithm (O(log(N)))
- simply check if the next element also has the same value O(1)
  When you find the first that is not duplicated, stop.

Those 3 points make O(N*(log(N)+1)) which is simply (O(N*log(N))).

So finally you get O(N) + 2*(O(N*log(N))) which is again (O(N*log(N))).